# Why can't we embed slices or maps into Go structs

Tags: go, struct, composition, embedding

I learnt that it is not allowed to embed slices or maps into Go structs. But I found two workarounds to this:

1. Declare the slice or map outside the struct and embed it into the struct

   ```
   var mySlice []int

   type myStruct struct {
     mySlice
   }
   ```
2. I don't really understand this second workaround, but I found it's called Composition and it's done by just omitting the var keyword when declaring the slice or map within the struct

   ```
   type myStruct struct {
     mySlice []int
   }
   ```

My first question is, can anyone explain why we can't directly embed slices and maps into a struct?

Second question: using the second workaround, is there any negative performance effect to that?

Third question: why do the first and second workaround work?

Comment: Second is not a "workaround" - you just declared a field in the struct. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/2

Comment: What you have in option 1 is definitely invalid. What you have in option 2 looks completely standard. What do you mean when you say "embed slices and maps into a struct"? Could you show an example of what you would call "embedding"?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta they probably typoed `var` -> `type`. Then it works.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta, I don't understand what you mean by option 1 is invalid, but it works. What I mean by the phrase "embed slices and maps into a struct" is what I saw on this website: https://mariadesouza.com/2017/09/29/embedding-in-go/

Comment: Your first example is invalid, not because you cannot embed slices into structs, but because you cannot embed _variables_ into structs. `mySlice` is a named variable, not a type.  If you change it to `type mySlice []int`, the rest of your coe works fine.

Answer (score 4):

[Spec: Struct types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an *embedded field*. An embedded field must be specified as a type name `T` or as a pointer to a non-interface type name `*T`, and `T` itself may not be a pointer type. The unqualified type name acts as the field name.

You can't embed a type like `map[int]string`, that's an anonymous type. Spec requires a *type name*. Even if you could embed that, it contains brackets which would make it disqualify from being an identifier, and again, spec says the *unqualified type name acts as the field name*.

Simply create a new type for it which you can then embed:

```
type mymap map[int]string

type s struct {
    mymap
}
```

When you embed a type in a struct, you omit the field name. In your second attempt:

```
type myStruct struct {
    mySlice []int
}
```

You did not omit the field name (it's `mySlice`), so this is not embedding, it's a regular, named field.